# How to format date without time using toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, date

I have a Date, which I want to convert to a string, but without the time, just the date part.

My current code:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 9, 08); //Wed Oct 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) 
var options = {weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"};

console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options)); 
// output: Wednesday, October 8, 2014 12:00:00 AM 
// what I'm looking for: Wednesday, October 8, 2014
```

How can I modify the options to not display time?

Comment: possible to use toDateString() as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Juste use `toLocaleDateString` instead of `toLocaleTimeString` and you should get the result you are expecting :

```
var date = new Date('2014', '9', '08'); //Wed Oct 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
var options = {weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"};
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```

returns : `"Wednesday, October 8, 2014"`

I will also second the above poster and recommend using moment.js; it is lightweight and very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with allowing the browser to determine the display format, you can use the `toDateString` or `toLocaleDateString` functions of the `Date` object.  You *will* get different results on different browsers.

Otherwise, consider using a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), so you can control the format to your liking.  For example:

```
moment([2014,9,8]).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY')   // "Wednesday, October 8, 2014"
```

Comment: I like moment but the dependency is just too large